# просмотреть типы данных в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

нужно просканировать таблицу на типы полей если поле типа int вывести в один список если varchar в дрогой.

```
$sTable=$db->get_results("SHOW COLUMNS FROM site_users");
if ($num = $db->num_rows > 0) {
 foreach ( $sTable as $row ){
  $sType=strval($row->Type);
  switch ($sType) {
   case preg_match('/^int/i',$sType): echo "Тип Ч $sSType ".$sType; break;   
   case preg_match('/^varchar/i',$sType): echo "Тип Т $sSType ".$sType; break;
   default:$sType = "Хз что это ";break; }
  //echo "<HR>"; print_r($row); echo "<HR>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN data_type = 'int' THEN column_name END) INTs,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN data_type = 'varchar' THEN column_name END) VARCHARs
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
  AND table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Полученные списки тупо Split.

Comment: Все бы ничего но ваш код работает в MS SQL а на MySQL он выводит ошибку

Comment: *ваш код работает в MS SQL* Вообще-то не должен. Нет там `GROUP_CONCAT()` *на MySQL он выводит ошибку* Тоже не должен - особенно если правильно указать БД и таблицу. Во всяком случае у меня работает без проблем.

Comment: Прошу прощение, забыл про ригистр. Спасибо большое!